# How to delete an item from a Map in aws Dynamodb using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in Dynamo db called `Settings` the unique keys is `email` and has an attribute called `display_names` this is type Map and has the following structure`{'123-456': "any name", '789-123': 'another name'}`

I'm trying to delete the name at with the attribute '123-456' with the following params

```
TableName: 'Settings',
        Key: {
            email: 'user@test.com',
        },
        UpdateExpression: 'DELETE display_names :p',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: '{":p" : {"S": 123-456}}'
    };
```

But when I run the code I get the following error `ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: \"11\"",`

I hope you can help me, thank you in advance!

Comment: I realized that the problem is that the Map key is a uuid, and when I try to access using square brackets but I get an error `Syntax error; token: \"\"\", near: \"[\"96\"",` so I'm wondering what would be the correct form to access the value

Answer (score 1):

You can use below `UpdateExpression` to remove a key from the map.

```js
const keyToDelete = '123-456';
const params = {
  TableName: 'Settings',
  Key: {
    email: 'user@test.com',
  },
  UpdateExpression: `REMOVE #parent.#key`, // Here. Note: use `` instead of '',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {  
    "#parent": 'display_names',
    "#key": keyToDelete
  },  
  ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW'
};
```

Comment: I have tried that before but I get the following error 
"Unable to update produect: ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: \"123\", near: \".123-\"",

Comment: I updated the answer, use [] to access attribute. Let’s correct double quotes , I edited by iPhone then the characters are not correctly

Comment: It seems that is not a valid syntax for Dynamo 
"Unable to update produect: ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: \"\"\", near: \"[\"123\"",